# Cortar string na última ocorrência de um caractere em uma string

Tags: mysql

Tenho um texto em uma coluna que tem informações separadas por "-"(hífen) e preciso remover a última e penúltima informação.

Exemplos:

- Transformar "`Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen`" em "`Informacoes - Separadas`";
- Transformar "`Informacoes separadas - Por - Hifen`" em "`Informacoes separadas`".

É possível fazer isso apenas em um `Select`?

Comment: Como se chama a tabel e a coluna, só para tentar ajuda-lo de acordo

Comment: Tanto faz, pode chamar de `Texto from tabela` ou só usar `select "Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen";` mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outras respostas não removem as últimas ocorrências igual eu precisava.
Elas removiam as primeiras ocorrências e concatenavam, portanto elas não funcionaram pro segundo caso: `Informacoes separadas - Por - Hifen`.

Acabei achando uma solução em uma [postagem antiga](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#c9069) nas referências do MySQL.
A solução procura pela posição do caractere na string invertida, subtrai a posição pelo tamanho da string e corta na posição encontrada, removendo assim na última posição do caractere desejado.

Fazendo isso duas vezes eu obtive o que precisava:

```
select 
  @string := 'Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen' as String, 
  @posCorte1 := length(@string) - locate('-', reverse(@string)) AS 'Posicao corte 1', 
  @stringCortada1 := left(@string, @posCorte1) AS 'Sem ultima ocorrencia', 
  @posCorte2 := length(@stringCortada1) - locate('-', reverse(@string)) AS 'Posicao corte 2',
  substr(@string,@posCorte2 + 1) as 'Parte retirada',
  left(@string, @posCorte2) AS 'String final' 
;
```

O `sql` acima resolveu meu problema, mas depois eu faço uma *function* a partir dele pra facilitar.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) para retornar as ocorrências após o delimitador, se o contador é positivo retorna as ocorrências a contar da esquerda até o final da string, se negativo retorna a partir da direita.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,delimitador,contador)
```

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen', '-', 1) as texto;
```

**Retorna:**

```
Informacoes
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen', '-', 2) as texto;
```

**Retorna:**

```
Informacoes - Separadas
```

**Exemplo 3:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen', '-', -2) as texto;
```

**Retorna:**

```
 Por - Hifen
```

Para retornar `Informacoes Separadas` sem o hífen, você pode utilizar uma combinação de `SUBSTRING_INDEX` e [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen', '-', 2),'-',1
    ),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('Informacoes - Separadas - Por - Hifen', '-', 2),'-',-1
    )
) as texto;
```

Comment: Boa solução, não conhecia @abfurlan

Answer (score 2):

Podes criar esta função:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

E depois aplica-la:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(informacoes, ' - ', 1) as info,
   SPLIT_STR(informacoes, ' - ', 2) as separadas
   FROM   informacoes;
```

Testei-a agora e funcionou